# Extra width from new left navigation causes elements to wrap

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Here is what I see on my profile page. I haven't thoroughly checked all pages, but I imagine this is not the only instance.

This is on a 1920px wide display.

[image: Screenshot of the User Profile edit page. The third tab for "Where do you code?" is on a second line below the first two instead of next to them. The second input field for Degree and school name is below and to the right of the first one.]

Comment: You should include screen dimensions and your current browser in bug reports where they are relevant.

Comment: Didn't even think about that. Added.

Comment: I'm able to duplicate on Chrome and Firefox on 1920x1080 but even if I expand the page across two monitors, the issue is visible. I don't think the left nav is causing this even if it happened when the changes were made.

Comment: This is on [the edit page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current); reproducible on Firefox 62.0a1.

Comment: I can't repro this on chrome via my Mac. Layout looks fine. Could it be OS dependent?

Comment: @JoeFriend See the answer. Looks like the build is already complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue, and sorry for inconvenience. This issue is related to the new left sidebar updates that shipped earlier today. A Less spacing variable wasn't correctly escaped within a width `calc` function and so failed to render the correct width.

This has been fixed and will be corrected with the next production build <strike>in the next hour or two</strike> building now.